# Unserializing an API return object (PHP/Ebay API)

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have been working with the Ebay api for a project and have found it great. I have however found a problem now, more PHP related.

When I read my items from Ebay, I store a bunch of details in the database. Currently, just for the sake of it really, I serialize the whole return object and store it in the database in a related table.

The idea being, that when I display my information, I have all the details to hand should I need them. The problem arises in that the pricing information is always in a sub object.

```
[ConvertedAdjustmentAmount] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
    (
        [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => eBayAmountType
        [_] => 0
        [currencyID] => USD
    )
```

As you can see when I unserialize my object, my cunning plan falls foul of the Incomplete class problem. I have checked the following question, without success.

[forcing access to __PHP_Incomplete_Class object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965611/forcing-access-to-php-incomplete-class-object-properties)

The main issue lies, as far as I can see, in that the price class is stored in the Ebay api, so how do I recreate it?

I have been reading this page, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php and trying to figure out, `unserialize_callback_func` which I can't figure out either, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What piece of code defines the class is irrelevant. What matters is that the code be **loaded** at the time you deserialize the object. As long as you've loaded the eBay API (in the same way you would when fetching a **new** object) before you try deserializing an existing one, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, so simple! I just included my Ebay soap client and it worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the libraries then you'll need to deal with the information prior to serializing your data. You can convert your object to a stdClass or shuffle it off to a class of your choice (one that you control, presumably). Depending on how much information you have - or how deep the information is - you could also store it as an array.