# Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
class user{
    public function __construct(){
    }
}
$user = new user;
$id = $_SESSION['user'];
```

which results in the error "Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array".
Changing `$_SESSION['user']` to `$_SESSION['_user']` corrects this.

I am only experiencing this in my development environment. My live environment does not produce this error.

My question: is there a configuration setting that is treating the Session key 'user' as a class object?

Answer (score 1):

When I have run into this it was due to calling session_start(); after the class definitions were loaded.  It needed to be called first.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are more things that can cause this issue:

1. register_globals is on - as said above. I mean, register_globals is soo STONE AGE !!! Just turn if OFF!
2. If you load an object from $_SESSION which has not been included before - setting autoloader may help, but from what I have tried, if it goes together with point 1 - this will NOT help (so again, please turn 1 off if still on..)
3. It is possible that the actual name of the session variable causes the problem -> e.g. $_SESSION['user'] - when loading the session, PHP (god knows why) tries to look for a class "User" and if it finds the class - tries to treat the session variable as an instances of this class, which may result in an incomplete class thing, becasue the CLass was not loaded yet, or simply becasue the structure of this variable is just wrong (because it holds different data of course). In my case it was a combination o 1 and 3. Simply renaming the session variable to $_SESSION['save-user'] or sth similar would fix the problem
4. if any of the above happens, you can try to use the code in this anwser, which fixes broken session objects [forcing access to __PHP_Incomplete_Class object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965611/forcing-access-to-php-incomplete-class-object-properties)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have register_globals enabled which means the global variable `$user` and the session variable `$_SESSION['user']` are the same thing, so when you do `$user = new user` your overwriting your session variable `['user']` with the new object

PHP unserialized everything stored in the session when you call `session_start` and PHP can't unserialize an object if its class hasn't been defined yet. When you attempt to do something like that PHP throws it into a special useless class called **__PHP_Incomplete_Class**.

this will fix problem

This will fix   problem  $_SESSION['user'] is an object, not an array, and you cannot access objects using array notation (ie: ['index'])*. If 'index' is a public property you access it using ->index, otherwise you'll need to add a method to your class for getting 'index' and call that method using ->get_index();

Comment: Mayank, I'm following your line of thought now. It does not seem to have anything to do with the user class. I'll report back later, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an instance of your class in a session, you will need to serialize it first. You can use the standard serialize() function in PHP. The retrieve your information, use the unserialize() function.

```
class User()
{
    private $id;
    // other

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
}

// Set the session
$newUser = new User();
$_SESSION['mySession'] = serialize($newUser);

// Retrieve session info
$myUser = unserialize($_SESSION['mySession']);
```

Comment: Rick, the Session['user'] and the object $user are different. My question is why is the Session['user'] being treated as a new instance of class user?

Comment: I don't believe that would happen if you'd serialize your instance